# How to create an instruction in llvm

Tags: llvm

I have tried like below
static CallInst *call = llvm::CallInst::Create(Fun, "", &Instruction);

but this is not working

(1)
Instruction* inst = ...;
auto *NewInstruction = new Instruction(..., inst );

Could some one give me an example ?

(2)
llvm::CallInst::Create

Could some one give me an example ?

Comment: You need to create an llvm builder I think. Look into that one.